# .LIFE domain on Heroku hosting is possible?

Tags: heroku, dns

Does anybody work with domains in **.life** zone? I heard that not all hostings allow to use this domains. Is it true for **Heroku**?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @Chris, I wondering too, it was my question.

Comment: Evgeny, my point is that Heroku works with custom domains. Do you have any specific reason to think it wouldn't work with this one? Why would it be an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku allow custom domain for pointing purpose which doesn't have any restriction as per docs.